# Error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] Server sent charset unknown to the client. Please, report to the developers dsn = mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to install ProjeQtOr on my computer with a mysql server but when I want to configure the database on mysql I receive this error message
Does anyone know how to fix this?
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdoWA.png)

I tried to reinstall mysql several times but no way to solve this problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.